# Кнопка inline отображается но при нажатии идет бесконечная загрузка (т.e. Не видит кнопку). это кнопка yes(2 уровня когда пользователь вводит массу )

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
import logging
import re

from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.types import CallbackQuery

import config
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import keyboards as kb
from callback_datas import start_callback, calc_liquid
from states import Test

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize bot and dispatcher
bot = Bot(config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def show_button(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(text="Hi,can I help you?",
                         reply_markup=kb.calc_choice)


@dp.callback_query_handler(start_callback.filter(name_btn="calc"))
async def calculator(call: CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer(cache_time=60)
    await call.message.answer("Enter mass of product in kg")
    await Test.Q1.set()


@dp.callback_query_handler(calc_liquid.filter(item_btn="yes"))
async def liquid_avaibility(call: CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer(cache_time=60)
    callback_data = call.data
    await call.message.answer("In btn Yes")


@dp.message_handler(state=Test.Q1)
async def answer_q1(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer = message.text
    if re.fullmatch(r'^(0|[1-9]\d*)([.,]\d+)?', answer):
        await state.update_data(answer1=answer)

        await message.answer(text="Do you have liquid in parcer?",
                             reply_markup=kb.liquid_choice)
    else:
        await message.answer("You enter wrong mass. Please enter right mass")
        await Test.Q1.set()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже решил, до того как вызвать кнопку закрыл машину состояние через 'await state.reset_state (with_data = False)' и сохранил данные чтоб в дальнейшем их использовать